# MFC Print Preview 'Prev' button not enabling when used with Objective Grid from Rogue Wave - Stingray Studio

Tags: mfc, print-preview, rogue-wave

I have an MFC app that uses Rogue Wave's Stingray Studio Objective Grid to display a dialog with a grid in it. When doing a print preview, the grid uses the MFC print preview mechanism to generate the print preview dialog. On the dialog I see all the buttons you would expect, including next and previous, and zoom in and zoom out. I have more than one page worth of data in the grid and so I see a scroll bar on the right, the Next button is enabled and the previous button is disabled. If I click on the next button, the dialog advances the preview to the next page of the data, and I see the scroll bar move down accordingly, but the Prev button does not become enabled. I can use the scroll bar to scroll in both directions, but the 'Prev' button never becomes enabled and the Next button never disables when I reach the last page. I see a similar problem with the Zoom buttons. I can zoom in, but the zoom out button never enables so I can never zoom out anymore.

Has anyone seen this sort of behaviour before and know what causes it?

Answer (score 0):

So it would seem that my problem boils down to the toolbar not getting messages to refresh itself. It should be getting a `WM_IDLEUPDATECMDUI` whenever the preview invalidates itself, but it is not. A sample app I found is working correctly and it does get those messages. What I believe is happening in my situation is that My code is in a DLL for an app which I do not control, and when the app catches messages, it swallows certain ones, including this one. I was able to resolve the issue with a kludge. I find the preview window and in the OnPrint virtual function I send the message to it's toolbar. This works quite well, but it is not very pretty.